# JQuery - Perform Action on Parent when Child has Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have multiple divs on a page which in turn, contain multiple inputs. I would like to change the background of any div who has a child input that is in focus and change it back again when focus moves to an input child of *another* div. So far I have the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="explain" id="block1">   
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>      
</div>

<div class="explain" id="block2">     
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" TabIndex="3"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" TabIndex="4"></asp:TextBox>                 
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('focusin', '.explain', function () {
        if (true) {
            $(this).animate({
                backgroundColor: "#e0f4fb"
            }, 1000);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('blur', '.explain', function () {
            $(this).animate({
                backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
            }, 1000);
    });

  });
</script>
```

This works fine if I tab from an input child of one div into another. For example if I move focus from 'TextBox1' to 'TextBox3', 'block1' will fade out and 'block2' will fade in. This is great.

However, the problem arises when I try changing to a different child input within the same div. For example if I tab from 'TextBox1' to 'TextBox2' this will fire the 'out of focus' followed by the 'in focus' animation again on the parent, thus fading 'block1' out and back in again.

So, is there any way in which I can change the background color of a parent div when one of its child inputs have focus and then revert it back ONLY when moving to an input child of another div?

Comment: trying using stop before you start the next animation $(this).stop().animate(

Comment: I've updated my example below with a link to a fiddle. I hope that helps.

Comment: Hey @Sunand, that did the trick! If you put that in an answer, I will mark it as the correct one.

Comment: @JohnP Its okay :) I am lazy :P

Comment: Why this `if (true) {` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the solution to my problem was the simple answer supplied by Sunland. Simply adding a .stop() before starting the next animation fixed the issue.

I.e. using this:

```
$(this).stop().animate({
   backgroundColor: "#e0f4fb"
}, 1000);
```

instead of this:

```
$(this).animate({
   backgroundColor: "#e0f4fb"
}, 1000);
```

A working example can be seen at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ly7jyvuf/8/

Thanks again to both Sunland and Gene for their help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried targeting the input directly, and when triggered alter the parent, like so:

```
$('input').on('focusin', function() {
    $(this).parents('.explain').animate({
            backgroundColor: "#e0f4fb"
        }, 1000);
});
```

And on blur:

```
$('input').on('blur', function() {
    $(this).parents('.explain').animate({
            backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
        }, 1000);
});
```

Here's a Fiddle to demonstrate this http://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/31yjdogc/1/. You will need jQueryUI, just in case you don't have it included yet.

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a million for looking at this Gene. I really appreciate it. Unfortunately, your fiddle example seems to be suffering the same problem as mine i.e. when you tab from textbox1 to textbox3 (both in the same div) the background fade out/in animation triggers. I have no doubt that you understood what I was looking for but, just to be on the safe side, I have edited my post to (hopefully) make things a little clearer. :-)